# working with String in java

Tags: java, string

In the given code,'s' is an object of class String.
When we pass 's' to a function,a copy of s will be created,which will be pointing to the same string.
but even then the changes made by the function are not getting reflected when done through method 1 but are getting reflected when we go by method 2.

Method 1:

```
class ST{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String s="Test";
        change(s);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    static void change(String s)
    {
        s=s+"test";

    }
}
```

Method 2:

```
class ST{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String s="Test";
        s=change(s);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    static String change(String s)
    {
        return s+"test";

    }
}
```

My question is, if every time a copy of the original reference is created, which is also pointing to the same string, then why does method one fail?

Comment: I don't see any question here.

Comment: Method 1 is altering the locally scoped variable `s` to point to a new instance of a string.  This new string is discarded once the function is exited.  The original variable `s` still points to the original string `Test`. 
 Once outside the method scope, back in `main` nothing has changed.  Method 2 is setting `main`'s variable `s` to the result of the function call, thereby changing `s` to point to a new string.

Comment: here s stores the refrence and changes made in the refrence should be reflected throughout....just asking.

Comment: Your code is more confusing because you use `s` as name of two *separate variables*:  one created within `main` method, other is name of `change` parameter. To limit some confusion try renaming one of them to lets say `x` like `change(String x){x=x+"test";}`. This lets see that we are modifying separate variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String objects are Immutables! You can't change them, so `s=s+"test"` creates a brand new String.

So the only way to manage it is your method number 2

Comment: Thanks for the answer...but does this mean that 's' in method 2 has started pointing to completely new string "Testtest"

Comment: No, what it means is that you will return a NEW String object, different from `s` with the value of `s` + test

Comment: I was talking about the 's' in main of method 2 in the line `s=change(s);`